# Automation : Selenium iphone(Mobile) Driver To Capture Network using Xcode iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, mobile, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using Xcode iPhone(Mobile) simulator to run Selenium iPhone WebDriver Automation scripts for mobile Websites. Is there anyway to capture Network-Traffic on iPhone simulator similar to Selenium RC Network capture or BrowserMob Proxy for Web Driver.

Please let me know if you know way to capture Network traffic on iPhone simulator programmatically.

I do see some tools like Wireshark or HTTPScoop to capture network traffic but I need in a pro grammatical way  to automate.

I need this scenario for pixel tracking.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Did you already try browsermob proxy? Is it not working with IPhoneDriver?

Comment: Can you provide your test setup? I really like that!